# Dominate convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis

$\Omega$ is open bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f_i\in H^1(\Omega)$ with $\|f_i\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq C$ where $C$ is constant independent of i, i,e., they are uniformly bounded in $L^2$ norm. $f_i$ converges to $f$ pointwisely. Is following true?
$$\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}\int_\Omega f_i=\int_{\Omega}f.$$
Is there any simple counterexample if not? Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is $H^1(\Omega)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Without loss of genearlity assume that $f=0$. Note that $\int_{|f_i| >T} |f_i| \leq \sqrt C \mu (\{x: |f_i(x)| >T\}$ by Holder /Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Also $\mu (\{x: |f_i(x)| >T\} \leq \frac 1 {T^{2}} \int |f_i|^{2}$ and $\int_{|f_i| \leq T} |f_i| \to 0$ by DCT. Hence $\int |f_i| d\mu \to 0$.